# Consuming Restful Web Services using C#

Tags: c#, rest, webservices-client

CA exposes Restful web services. My client wants to utilize C# to invoke these Restful web services. I have c# experience, but zero experience with web services with C#. Any pointers on where to start, and what good books (paper back or ebook) will be great.

Comment: This isn't quite the appropriate question for SO, however, http://www.newtonsoft.com/json is a good place to start.

Comment: Maybe [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

Comment: If c# is the client consuming the web service, look at System.Net.HttpClient.

Comment: It may depend on what kind of C# project you are going to create. If it is a web-based project, referencing ASP.NET would help. If it is a Silverlight project, it may be done differently even thought it is still done with C#. I would propose figuring out what type of .NET project you are going to create first, then figure out how to consume the service.

Comment: The project type would be a Web Page. so essentially an ASP MVC application...but that is Phase 1. Phase 2 would be to have a Windows Phone application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though your question is off-topic for SO format, I'm posting this answer because REST is becoming mainstream nowadays.

For consuming RESTful APIs you could use any http client you can get, as long as it allows you to properly customize the requests.

I recommend [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) for this purpose. I've used it before and it does it's job.

Comment: Thank you. I will give that a go. I am hoping they have a beginners tutorial.